# base url changed

Tags: base-url

I changed the base url and now i can't get into the admin page.
what i've seen on this forum is to change the value in the database
but i can't connect to my database with mysql workbench

so if someone could help me with the command line for terminal

```
mysql> describe core_config_data
    -> ;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| config_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| scope     | varchar(8)       | NO   | MUL | default |                |
| scope_id  | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| path      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | general |                |
| value     | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_url%';
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                  | value                   |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
|         9 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_url | this is what i need to change! |
|        10 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_url   | i deleted my ipadres     |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the values via the terminal you should just have to run:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'your url' WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'your secure url' WHERE path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Remember to make sure you include the trailing slash on the domain.

Comment: I reinstalled magento, but thanks anyway

Comment: When you make changes to the `core_config_data` table, you must always clear the Magento cache so config data gets re-read out of the table. Also, on moving to a new server, make sure proper file/directory permissions and ownership are set so Magento can read/write its cache from `var/cache` or it will install the cache elsewhere and refuse to allow the new values written to `core_config_data` to be read.